# How to hide a JPanel in a JFrame then add another JPanel from other class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a basic JFrame that when the jButtonLogin is clicked, i want to hide the jPanelLogin , and add to jPanelPrincipal my panel PainelPrincipal , PainelPrincipal is a class that extends from JPanel . But actually when I click in my button , my System.out.println is showed but none of components from PainelPrincipal is displayed.

My main class :

```js
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/GUIForms/JFrame.java to edit this template
 */
package gestaomcd;

import formularios.PainelPrincipal;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/**
 *
 * @author mathe
 */
public class main extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private PainelPrincipal painelPrincipal;
    
    
    public main() {
        initComponents();
        setTitle("Gestão MCD v1.0");
        configTela();
    }

    private void configTela() {
        configBotoes();
    }
    
    private void configBotoes(){
        jButtonLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                login();
            }
        });
    }
    
    private void login(){
        
        painelPrincipal = new PainelPrincipal();
        
        jPanelLogin.setVisible(false);
        jPanelPrincipal.add(painelPrincipal);
        jPanelPrincipal.repaint();
        
        painelPrincipal.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        painelPrincipal.setSize(this.getSize());
        
        jPanelPrincipal.add(painelPrincipal);
        jPanelPrincipal.revalidate();
        jPanelPrincipal.repaint();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanelPrincipal = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanelLogin = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanelHeader = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabelHeader = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanelLogin1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabelUsuario = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabelSenha = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextFieldUsuario = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextFieldSenha = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jButtonLogin = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabelLoginStatus = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanelHeader.setBackground(javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults().getColor("Actions.Yellow"));
        jPanelHeader.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));

        jLabelHeader.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Roboto", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabelHeader.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabelHeader.setText("Gestão MCD");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanelHeaderLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanelHeader);
        jPanelHeader.setLayout(jPanelHeaderLayout);
        jPanelHeaderLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanelHeaderLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanelHeaderLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabelHeader, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanelHeaderLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanelHeaderLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanelHeaderLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabelHeader, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 37, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jPanelLogin1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Login"));

        jLabelUsuario.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Roboto", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabelUsuario.setText("Usuário:");

        jLabelSenha.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Roboto", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabelSenha.setText("Senha:");

        jButtonLogin.setText("ENTRAR");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanelLogin1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanelLogin1);
        jPanelLogin1.setLayout(jPanelLogin1Layout);
        jPanelLogin1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanelLogin1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanelLogin1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanelLogin1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(jPanelLogin1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanelLogin1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabelUsuario)
                            .addComponent(jLabelSenha))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanelLogin1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jTextFieldUsuario)
                            .addComponent(jTextFieldSenha)))
                    .addGroup(jPanelLogin1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabelLoginStatus, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 241, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButtonLogin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 131, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanelLogin1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanelLogin1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanelLogin1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(12, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanelLogin1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabelUsuario)
                    .addComponent(jTextFieldUsuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanelLogin1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabelSenha)
                    .addComponent(jTextFieldSenha, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanelLogin1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButtonLogin)
                    .addComponent(jLabelLoginStatus)))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanelLoginLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanelLogin);
        jPanelLogin.setLayout(jPanelLoginLayout);
        jPanelLoginLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanelLoginLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanelHeader, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanelLogin1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanelLoginLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanelLoginLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanelLoginLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanelHeader, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanelLogin1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanelPrincipalLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanelPrincipal);
        jPanelPrincipal.setLayout(jPanelPrincipalLayout);
        jPanelPrincipalLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanelPrincipalLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanelPrincipalLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanelLogin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );
        jPanelPrincipalLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanelPrincipalLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanelLogin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanelPrincipal, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanelPrincipal, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new main().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonLogin;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelHeader;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelLoginStatus;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelSenha;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelUsuario;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanelHeader;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanelLogin;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanelLogin1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanelPrincipal;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jTextFieldSenha;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldUsuario;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

My PainelPrincipal class:

```js
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/GUIForms/JPanel.java to edit this template
 */
package formularios;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

/**
 *
 * @author mathe
 */
public class PainelPrincipal extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form PainelPrincipal
     */
    public PainelPrincipal() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        initComponents();
        System.out.println("criou");
        
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");

        jLabel1.setText("reste");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(156, 156, 156)
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(129, 129, 129)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)))
                .addContainerGap(169, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(71, 71, 71)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(150, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: You'll want to use a CardLayout. The tutorial can be found here: [CardLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: And here, `jPanelPrincipal.add(painelPrincipal);`, you're adding a component to the `jPanelPrincipal` JPanel but you're ignoring its layout, the GroupLayout, which doesn't do well with adding other JPanels in this fashion. Again, use a CardLayout to swap.

Comment: You can edit the question to remove the HTML/JavaScript markers around code that is Java code.  All you need do is indent the code four spaces, the StackOverfliw system can then work out it is Java, not HTML/JavaScript.